# Need help with wire connections and code

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I am currently working on a keypad door lock mechanism (Similar to this project, [Keypad door lock](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut11.php)).

The issues with the code I have is that the keypad attached to my board does not allow me to type the full password. Only the first value displayed on the LCD screen moves but no value is excepted. Also the buttons used to open and close the servo motor do not operate as intended.

Fritzing diagram

[image: Fritzing diagram]

Photo of breadboard

[image: Photo of breadboard]

Below is the code I currently have:

```
//LCD config
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);

#include <Servo.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

//Variables
int mot_min = 90;   //min servo angle  (set yours)
int mot_max = 180; //Max servo angle   (set yours)
int character = 0;
int activated = 0;
char Str[16] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '-', '*', '*', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '};
//               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11  12    13   14  15

//Pins
Servo myservo;
int buzzer = 11;   //pin for the buzzer beep
int external = 12; //pin to inside open
int internal = 13; //pin to inside close

//Keypad config
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '4', '7', '*'},
  {'2', '5', '8', '0'},
  {'3', '6', '9', '#'},
  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(10); //attach the servo to pin D10
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(external, INPUT);
  pinMode(internal, INPUT);
  //Init the screen and print the first text
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("      -***     ");
  //put the servo in the close position first
  myservo.write(mot_min);

}

void loop() {
  ///////////////EMERGENCY OPEN/CLOSE/////////
  if (digitalRead(external) == LOW) // if (digitalRead(external))
  {
    myservo.write(mot_max);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
    lcd.print("INSIDE  OPEN");
    activated = 2;
    analogWrite(buzzer, 240);
    delay(250);
    analogWrite(buzzer, 200);
    delay(250);
    analogWrite(buzzer, 180);
    delay(250);
    analogWrite(buzzer, 250);
    delay(250);
    analogWrite(buzzer, LOW);


    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
    lcd.print("WELLCOME");

    lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
    lcd.print("ELECTRONOOBS");


    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("DOOR  OPEN");
    lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
    lcd.print("ELECTRONOOBS");
    delay(500);

  }

  if (digitalRead(internal) == LOW) // if (digitalRead(internal))
  {
    myservo.write(mot_min);
    activated = 0;
    character = 0;
    Str[6] = '-';
    Str[7] = '*';
    Str[8] = '*';
    Str[9] = '*';
    Str[10] = ' ';
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(Str);
  }

  ///////////////KEYPAD OPEN/CLOSE////////////
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey(); //this function reads the presed key

  if (customKey != NULL) { // if (customKey)

    if (character == 0)
    {
      Serial.println(customKey);
      Str[6] = customKey;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(Str);

    }

    if (character == 1)
    {
      Serial.println(customKey);
      Str[7] = customKey;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(Str);

    }

    if (character == 2) {
      {
        Serial.println(customKey);
        Str[8] = customKey;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(Str);

      }

      if (character == 3)
      {
        Serial.println(customKey);
        Str[9] = customKey;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(Str);

      }

      if (character == 4)
      {
        Serial.println(customKey);
        Str[10] = customKey;
        activated = 1;

      }
      character = character + 1;
    }

    if (activated == 1)
    {
      /*Change your password below!!!
        Change each of Str[6], Str[7], Str[8], Str[9]*/

      // if (Str[10] = 'A' && ...)
      if (Str[10] == 'A' && character == 5 && Str[6] == '3' && Str[7] == '0' && Str[8] == '0' && Str[9] == '7' )
      {
        myservo.write(mot_max);
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
        lcd.print("ACCEPTED");
        activated = 2;
        analogWrite(buzzer, 240);
        delay(250);
        analogWrite(buzzer, 200);
        delay(250);
        analogWrite(buzzer, 180);
        delay(250);
        analogWrite(buzzer, 250);
        delay(250);
        analogWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        delay(1000);

        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
        lcd.print("WELLCOME");
        delay(500);
        lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
        lcd.print("ELECTRONOOBS");
        delay(1000);

        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
        lcd.print("DOOR  OPEN");
        lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
        lcd.print("ELECTRONOOBS");

      }
      else
      {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
        lcd.print("PASSWORD ERROR");
        lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
        lcd.print("TRY  AGAIN");
        analogWrite(buzzer, 150);
        delay(3000);
        analogWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        character = 0;
        Str[6] = '-';
        Str[7] = '*';
        Str[8] = '*';
        Str[9] = '*';
        Str[10] = ' ';
        activated = 0;
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
        lcd.print("PASSWORD");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(Str);
      }
    }
    if (activated == 2)
    {
      if (customKey == 'B' )
      {
        myservo.write(mot_min);
        activated = 0;
        character = 0;
        Str[6] = '-';
        Str[7] = '*';
        Str[8] = '*';
        Str[9] = '*';
        Str[10] = ' ';
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("    PASSWORD");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(Str);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

To re-iterate, With this code now the LCD screen displays `PASSWORD` but when I enter the password into the keypad only the first number changes value and it does not move to the second value.

Comment: you have not described any problems and you have not asked any questions .... voting to close as `unclear what you're asking` ..... please update your post .... include a description of expected behavior, observed behavior and any errors that you get

Comment: This is the issue I'm having (https://youtu.be/aWixfn1pe3A).

Comment: needs more re-callable subroutines. a lot more...

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to have an excess of `{` here:

```
if (character ==2) {
{    <<<< Remove this
```

and then remove the excess `}` at the end of the code.

It would seem that this is affecting the logic of your code, as you've ended up inadvertently grouping some `if`s within another `if`.

---

To avoid this type of situation, you need to be much more consistent with your code style (i.e. formatting/indentation).

Either use:

```
if (character ==2) {
```

or

```
if (character ==2) 
{
```

but *don't mix them*. Otherwise you'll end up in a right old muddle.

If you keep your coding style consistent, then you'll see, in a flash, something that is out of place - merely by quickly scrolling through the code.

---

In addition, use the `Tools ► Auto Format` menu item in the Arduino IDE to correctly format your code and make it easy to read.

Comment: Changed the code with your suggestion but still receiving similar output issue.

Comment: As it is compiling, it is most likely a logical error within your code. I strongly suggest that you tidy the code, as the indentation is all over the place, and nigh impossible to follow.  If you indent it correctly then you'll see whether the `if` statements are grouped correctly and follow logical sequences. The indentation has become significantly worse since your last edit. You have, inexplicably, removed the indentation on large sections of the code

Comment: I apologize for the indentation but if it helps a very similar code that I'm using is on (http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut11.php). Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could no longer follow your code, with the indentation removed, and gave up. Sorry. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I've correctly formatted your code for you, please check the edit that I made to your question, in order to see how you should have improved it. Cheers :-) Note that I have not changed the code, nor corrected it, as it would change the nature of your question.  Hopefully now people can easily work out what's wrong with the code and will post an answer.